# show AlertDialog based on condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I want to show a *What's New* style `AlertDialog` to inform users what has changed in my app after updating. I've created the following function to see if the app has been updated:

```
  Future<bool> checkNewVersion() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    String appVersion = packageInfo.version;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? currVersion = prefs.getString("version");

    print("App version: $appVersion");
    print("Current version: $currVersion");

    if (currVersion == null) {
      await prefs.setString("version", appVersion);
      return true;
    }

    if (currVersion != appVersion) return true;

    return false;
  }
```

When this function is called in the `build` method below, the print statements output the following, but the alert dialog is not shown:

```
flutter: App version: 2.0
flutter: Current version: null
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (checkNewVersion() == true) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) =>
      AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("What's New / Que ha Cambiado"),
        content: Text(updateInfo),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      // app main menu
      ...
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Performing an async operation to get the result. So when performing an async function that returns some Future you must await for it otherwise it will return you an incomplete future.

So when calling **checkNewVersion()**

You should await for its result like

```
var versionResult = await checkNewVersion();
```

Your code will be like

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var versionResult = await checkNewVersion();
    if (versionResult) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) =>
      AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("What's New / Que ha Cambiado"),
        content: Text(updateInfo),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      // app main menu
      ...
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your `checkNewVersion` is an async function so you have to wait for its result, Try this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool result = await checkNewVersion();
    if (result) {
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) =>
      AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("What's New / Que ha Cambiado"),
        content: Text(updateInfo),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      // app main menu
      ...
    );
  }
```